# Add a pop up with a form when a point on highcharts is clicked

Tags: highcharts, highslide

I am using highcharts to click on a point and the clickevent opens up a highslide html. In this highslide html, I would like to add a form. The problem is that the form elements do not work.

How do I add a pop up with a form when a point on highcharts is clicked?

Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {


      chart: {type: 'spline',
      },
      title: {text: ''},
      series: [{
          name: 'mean value',
          showInLegend: false,
          data: {{ water_data_f }},
          color: 'green',
          cursor: 'pointer',

            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 4
            },


          point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {

                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },

                            maincontentText:
                               'Recommendation for Quality Imporvement:' + '<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"> 
                        });
                    }
                }}



      }]

  });
```

How do I add form fields to highslide? Is there a better way to add a form when a point on a highchart is clicked?

Comment: Hi @user1390000, Unfortunately, `highslide` is no longer a supported library by Highcharts. You can add a popup with a form by using basic JS code. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qpcx0k9a/

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for your reply. How do I position the pop up over the point that is clicked?

Comment: Hi @jethanger, No problem. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfev6rpy/